# Using a custom Oracle DB sequence in Grails id generation

Tags: oracle, grails, grails-orm, grails3

I have a Grails (v. 3.3.8) app with some scaffolded views which are based on tables in my Oracle 12c database. It all works well with a naive incremental ID generator but in order for it to work 100% according to the specification, I need to have it take the ID's from the database's sequences. For every table named `A_B_C`, I have a corresponding sequence named `A_B_C_SEQ`.

So normally, with SQL, I would get the next ID with a query like this: `select A_B_C_SEQ.nextVal as seq from dual;`. How do I go about translating it to Grails/GORM, so that it uses the sequence as well?

Comment: I am not 100% sure with Oracle, but with PostgreSQL you add the sequence to the domain class mapping like this
```
    static mapping = {
        id generator:'sequence', params:[sequence: 'log_event_id_seq']
    }
```

Comment: @OlavGrønåsGjerde - ha, that really is all it takes! Thanks a lot, if you want to upgrade your comment to an answer, I'd happily accept it :)